# Error al ejecutar el codigo en Java

Tags: java, archivo

estoy intentando hacer un programa y pese a que no se detecta ningun error en el codigo, este no funciona. Estoy intentando hacer un programa que contenga una propiedad ruta a un archivo y las palabras contenidas en el.
El codigo sería este:

```
    public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        boolean ejecucion=true;
        
        do{
         System.out.println("Escoger el programa de contar palabras");
         int opcion = Integer.parseInt(leerTeclado());
         switch(opcion){
             case 1:{
                 contarPalabrasArchivo();
                 break;
             }
             default:{
                 System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                 break;
             }
         }
        }while(ejecucion);
    }
    
   
    
    public static String leerTeclado (){
    String retorno="";
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    retorno = sc.nextLine();
    return retorno;   
    }
    
    public static void contarPalabrasArchivo(){
        Contador contador = new Contador();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la ruta");
        contador.setArchivo(new File(leerTeclado()));
        contador.contarPalabras();
    }
}
```

Algo esta fallando, me salta enseguida el error y no me lee ni siquiera el método para insertar el texto. No se donde puede estar el error si en el main o en la clase auxiliar.

Esta sería la clase contador. No la puedo poner como código porque me rechaza la edición al haber exceso de código.

```
public class Contador {
    
    
    File archivo;

    public File getArchivo() {
        return archivo;
    }

    public void setArchivo(File archivo) {
        this.archivo = archivo;
    }

    public Contador(File archivo) {
        this.archivo = archivo;
    }

    public Contador() {
    }
    
    //Metodo de lectura
    
    public void contarPalabras(){
        try(BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo))){
            String linea= bfr.readLine();
            int contador = 0;
            while (linea!=null){
                String palabras[]=linea.split(" ");
                contador+=palabras.length;
                System.out.println(linea);
                linea= bfr.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("El numero de palabras obtenido es de " +contador);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Contador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Contador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error te genera?,como esta estructurado la clase Contador? [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/525978/edit)

Comment: Agrega la clase Contador.

Comment: Estoy intentando meter el código editando la pregunta pero no me deja porque me dice que estoy metiendo principalmente código, sabeis alguna otra manera de meter el código?

Comment: Significa que debes poner también lo que te sale en logs o consola cuando ejecutas ésto y un archivo de prueba que contenga info similar a la que usas para probarlo

Comment: @Gonzmaister que error es el que se muestra? que tipo de archivo debes leer

Comment: @Gonzmaister no debe tener problema si usas la ruta correcta del archivo y este es un archivo de texto plano.

Comment: @Jorgesys es un archivo txt, el problema es que el programa casca ya directamente sin ejecutarse. No llega ni a ejecutar el método para introducir la ruta.

Comment: @jorgesys te he pegado el error que me sale en la ejecucion.

Comment: @Gonzmaister gracias, me parece que el problema es otro, limpia y  crea nuevamente el proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

El usuario debe introducir la ruta correcta de un archivo que exista, ya que en base a esto crea un objeto `File`, ejemplo:

```
C:\Datos\archivo.txt
```

**El formato del archivo, debe ser un archivo de texto plano, sin formato,si usas otro tipo de archivo se generaría un error o no se leería correctamente,** Puedes crear este tipo de archivos usando "notepad"